# Horizontal parallax scrolling using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get horizontal parallax effect. I have two child divs inside a parent div. I want to move both the div in opposite direction while scrolling with different speed. However it isn't working. I suspect use of top and left property may be the reason for the error. However i do need top and left property to place the divs in exact position.

My HTML:

```
<div id='frst' style= 'height:600px;'>
</div>
<div class= 'div1' style= " position:relative;width: 100%; height: 500px; background-color: red; top: 20%;">
    <div id= 'image'>
    </div> 
    <div id= 'image2'>
    </div>
</div>
```

No my CSS:

```
#image{ background:green ; width:100px; height: 100px; top:20px; position: absolute;}
#frst{color:white; }
#image2{ background: yellow;  width:100px;height: 100px; left: 60%;top:29px;position: absolute;}
```

JS I am using to move divs #image and #image2 either left or right on scroll:

```
function parallax() {
   var image= document.getElementById('image');
   var image2= document.getElementById('image2');

   image.style.margin-right= -(window.pageYOffset/ 10) + 'px';
   image2.style.margin-left= -(window.pageYOffset/ 9) + 'px';

}

window.addEventListener("scroll",parallax,false)
```

Comment: Can you explain as to what exactly is not working? Or rather what is desired?

Comment: Ok I want to animate divs #image towards right and #image2 towards left while scrolling. However when I am scrolling neither of them moves. If I remove the top:20px and left:60% from my #image,#image2 CSS properties, it does animates but in the process their position is compromised and they are dragged outside their parent div. Can i get an alternate JS code or should i have another CSS property for them

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting?
https://jsfiddle.net/0or5cgz4/7/

Added right to #image and #first as position relative and set width/height

```
#image{ background:green ; width:100px; height: 100px; top:0px;right:0; position: absolute;}
#frst{color:white;position:relative; width:100px;height:100px;}
```

Comment: But the divs have to animate from their positions and not from positions left:0 and right:0 on scroll. How to achieve that?

Comment: just set your initial position on page load

Comment: Thats not working. When scrolling , its overwriting the initial positions  and animates right from the edges. Please help me out